# Cant get a reference to ACE using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

http://plnkr.co/edit/bSm4nYJ0TmUqylidxkqt?p=preview

I am trying to use requirejs to inject a reference to the ACE editor javascript library.
The object which nests the ace reference returns just fine, but the ace property of that object is undefined. What am I missing in my setup?

Code is as follows.

I return an object using define. the define function declares a dependency on the ace library which is local (console shows me the ace.js resource loaded).

```
define(["./libs/ace/ace"],function(ace){
return {
        ref: ace,
        msg: "alive"
    }
```

});

My data-main target for requirejs is my script.js file which is as follows...

```
require(["js/testace"],function(testace){console.log(testace);});
```

My file structure is as follows...

[image]

...And my console output is as follows

Object {ref: undefined, msg: "alive"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it by using this code:
Replace the `/static/ace`, with `lib/ace`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">
    function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
            + window.location.pathname.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/"),

        paths: {
            ace: "/static/ace"
        }
    });

    require(["ace/ace"], function (ace) {
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1017

Checkout this page if you get some crazy errors: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html

Originally answered here: [How to load ace editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599597/how-to-load-ace-editor/19132269#19132269)